# I want Date format in IST extension(November 12th 2013 - 11:58 AM IST)

Tags: javascript

I am using

```
"Tue Nov 12 2013 11:58:53 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"..match(/\(([^\)]+)\)$/)[1]).match(/\b(\w)/g).join("");.
```

But it is not working in IE10. Please help me to get exptected format.
thanks

Comment: Did you notice the double dot in `..match` ?

Comment: @MatteoTassinari Also I'm not necessarily sure he put the **dot** at the end of `.join("");.` on purpose.

Comment: @Tafari right! It shouldn't be there...

Comment: @MatteoTassinari anyway his question suggests that the code is not working only in IE10 as he only mentioned that browser, which is obviously not true...

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
"Tue Nov 12 2013 11:58:53 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)".match(/\(([^)]+)\)$/)[1].match(/\b(\w)/g).join(""); // == "IST"
```

But please keep in mind to make proper verification should the base string be different from that static one.